# What is this android widget?

Tags: android, widget, textview, android-appwidget

I'm trying to find this widget:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6HTL.jpg

I tried looking online and the source code of the calendar app but no luck, I like this widget
so please help me.
Anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That would appear to be a `Spinner`, or at least something styled to look like a `Spinner`.

Comment: you know where can I find this style?

Comment: @user2675138 it is because the theme is Holo Light. That is how you will get that style.